# How to make this mysql query display a DISTINCT row?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT message_group.group_id, messages.*
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN message_group ON message_group.group_id = messages.group_id
WHERE message_group.username = 'admin'
OR message_group.recipients = 'admin'
ORDER BY messages.id DESC
```

Here is how it displays the data, even though I specified `DISTINCT message_group.group_id`

[image]
Why does it do this? How can I have it display only one `group id`?

More reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167801/how-to-order-message-groups-messages-just-like-imessage

Comment: Which other records should it display?  The results are `distinct` per the entire record.  You can "fake" your results with `group by group_id`, but this will only return arbitrary random values for the other rows...

Comment: True, do you think you could give me suggestions on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167801/how-to-order-message-groups-messages-just-like-imessage

Comment: Please post your expected output. Probably you are misjudging  `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT message_group.group_id, messages.*
FROM messages INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MAX(`timestamp`) AS latest,
        group_id
     FROM messages
     GROUP BY group_id) m2 
     ON messages.group_id = m2.group_id AND messages.`timestamp` = m2.`timestamp`
LEFT JOIN message_group ON message_group.group_id = messages.group_id
WHERE message_group.username = 'admin'
OR message_group.recipients = 'admin'
ORDER BY messages.id DESC
```